# Javascript Sidebar error - Sidebar display before clicking the sidebar button

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript toggle button is not working.

When I resize the screen it is already activated.

Note: If you don't Understand then please check it out at http://www.createchhub.com
and resize the screen.

The Navbar is dropdown but I want it drop down when I click the button.

[image]

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').addClass('js');
        var $menu = $('#menu'),
            $menulink = $('.menu-link');

        $menulink.click(function() {
            $menulink.toggleClass('active');
            $menu.toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the HTML CODE:<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Menu</a>

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsbin.com/gahosogipa/edit?html,js,output). What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: please provide complete in format for testing.

Comment: See the website. When i resize the website the toggle automatically turns on. I want it to open when i press the button on the navigation bar
www.createchhub.com
@AjayKumarOad

Comment: I got it. that is not a toggle it's called menu bar. am i right?

Comment: yes! @AjayKumarOad

Comment: I think you need to update your question by adding or replacing toggle word with sidebar specifically. which is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**  you were calling your toggle method on document ready. that's why it was automatically opened when doc is ready.

**Solution:** try this, it fulfills your requirements.

**Javascript:**

```
<script >

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('js');
  var $menu = $('#menu'),
  $menulink = $('.menu-link');
});

$menulink.click(function() {
  $menulink.toggleClass('active');
  $menu.toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

---

**HTML**

```
<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Yes i did. Fast uni ka naam mat dubao bhai :D Come on do something!

Comment: Well my code seems to be fine. now i need two things one what is the error. and complete code to test it may be other code is making issue just to be sure.! nh dubane dunga!